# Classic ASP VBScript - refresh given page

Tags: asp-classic

I think that this is something very easy, but I cannot get this to work.

I have a form with a button "Delete". It calls www.mypage.com/adm/ads.asp?del=12.
So list.asp sees that there is a querystring with del=12 and deletes correspoding item.
After delete I want to refresh this page (something like Response.Redirect www.mypage.com/adm/ads.asp), so that querystring del=12 disappears.
I cannot get it working.

```
If (Request.QueryString("del").Count > 0) Then      
id = Request.QueryString("del") 
sql = "delete from Ads where ID = " & id & ""
on error resume next
conn.Execute sql   
If err<>0 then
    Response.Write("Delete error!")
Else            
    Response.Redirect http://www.mypage.com/adm/ads.asp     
    //Call opener.location.reload()
End if
```

The page is reloaded, but del doesn't disappear from query string.

Comment: Please keep in mind that this is vulnerable to SQL injection. If I pass `?del=0 OR 1=1` your entire table would be deleted.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will modify this. however, this is admin panel and not so important, as admin is allowed to delete all ads.

Comment: Considering you also use a GET request to delete, I could also add an image to my own site with the `src` tag pointing to `www.yourpage.com/adm/ads.asp?del=12 or 1=1` and if you visit my site, your entire table would be deleted by you. So even if something is only ment for you/admins, always write proper code.

Answer (score 2):

The parameter to `Response.Redirect` should be a string - what you have is a syntax error:

```
Response.Redirect http://www.mypage.com/adm/ads.asp
```

Should be:

```
Response.Redirect "http://www.mypage.com/adm/ads.asp"
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it generic and not mess with raw URLs you can have such code instead:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME"))
```

The SCRIPT_NAME server variable will return the relative path of the currently executing script, no matter what the page is called and where it's located.